# Reduce with higher-order callback parameter

Tags: javascript, callback, reduce, higher-order-functions

I have tried many ways to get the parent parameter to be visible to the reduce's callback function but I must be missing something...

```
// Static
var y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].reduce(
    function(arr, x){
        arr.push(Math.pow(2, x));
        return arr},[]);
console.log(y);

// Dynamic
var lambda = function(arr, func) {
    return (function(f) { return arr.reduce(function(a, x) {
        a.push(f(x));
        return a;
    }, [])})(func);
}
var y = lambda([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],function(x){return Math.pow(x);});
console.log(y);
```

***Output:***

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]  
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

<kbd>[**DEMO @ JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/Fqy4L/)</kbd>

Comment: What do you mean by `parent parameter`?

Comment: I want to pass `func` to be visible to the reduce function.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `2` in `Math.pow(x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one of the parameters to `Math.pow`. You might wanna invoke the `lambda` like this

```
var y = lambda([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], function(x) {
    return Math.pow(2, x);
});
```

Also, you don't have to complicate the `lambda` construction with an IIFE. It can be simply

```
var lambda = function(arr, func) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, x) {
        a.push(func(x));
        return a;
    }, []);
}
```

**Edit:** As you yourself suggested in the comments you can use `Array.prototype.map`, like this

```
console.log(arr.map(function(x) {
    return Math.pow(2, x);
}));
```

Comment: Although you answered second, you responded first. I will accept your answer but I will delete this post because it was a syntax error.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: You shouldn't delete it, but we might close it.

Comment: OK, I will vote to close my own question ;-p

Comment: I just realized that I wrote an `Array.map()` function...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl lol, even I realize that now... :) Included that also in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about the first argument in `Math.pow`:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------v
lambda([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], function(x) { return Math.pow(2, x); });
```

Comment: "Welcome to Whose Code is it Anyway, the site where syntax is screwed up and the points don't matter"